# PHP start_session seems to disable css

Tags: php, css, session

When I tried to use start_session in PHP, it seems to disable my cascaded style sheet functionality. My html page layout looks out of order e.g the menu will to the bottom where it suppose to be on top. Is there a way to use start_session that does not interfere with the css ?

Below is the code snipet:

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mod_style.css" /> 
 </head>
```

Comment: please provide more code. When do you start the session? You can NOT start the session after you have sent data to the client! start_session must be before the first `echo`, `print` or `var_dump`

Comment: remove all the html and test only with `<?PHP session_start(); ?>` does it show any error? are you sure the filename+extension is correct (I mean, .php)?

Comment: remove the newline between the ?> and the doctype declaration

Comment: @Orangepill this shouldn't matter. spaces (also NL/CR) and comments are allowed. look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#conformant-documents)

Comment: have you got a link to the site as the code you have presented seems ok, so the problem is a little deeper. My initial reaction would have been that you may have left a php tag off of an include file or something like that.

Comment: @redreggae thought non doctype first line would trigger quirks mode

Comment: @Orangepill ah learned something new..this is true for IE 6,7,8. read more [here](http://nimbupani.com/the-truth-about-doctypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have no recollection of PHP's session ever interfering with loading stylesheets, or any other non-PHP-session related code. Have you checked whether the path to your CSS file is correct?

You could quickly open your page's source (usually CTRL + U in browser on Windows) and try to follow the link to your CSS file. If you get a 404 Error page, you definitely need to change your path.

If your path is correct (like, if the stylesheet loads after you've removed the PHP Session line) then your error is not caused by the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code editor's output saved file encoding. For example, if you use MS Notepad and saved your file in Unicode, you may find a special character in the first line of the file that causes errors and misfunction of session_start.

To be ensured, check your page source from the browser.

> What I'm talking about is saving files as ANSI vs UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 0):

If you have confirmed that your style sheets are actually loading via developer tools like firebug or chrome dev tools and you are testing in old IE. The newline at the end of the session_start call may be the culprit. A non-doctype first line will throw those browsers into quirks mode and you style will go wonky on you.

To eliminate this you can just remove the newline like:

```
<?php session_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score -1):

Give complete path to style.css instead of relative path as follow:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/css/mod_style.css" />
```

Try this, I am sure this will help you.